# Inclusão de Imagem em Banco de Dados - LongBlob

Tags: java, mysql

Estou codificando um cadastro simples, onde o mesmo necessita gravar também no banco de dados uma foto, que deve ser do tibo BLOB.

Essa é minha Classe Pessoa:

```
public class Pessoa {

    private Integer idPessoa;
    private String nome;
    private Date dataNascimento;
    private String cpf;    
    private byte[] foto;
```

Essa é minha DAO de inclusão:

```
public class PessoaDAO {
    public void addPessoa(Pessoa pessoa) {
        Conecta c = new Conecta();
        try {              
            if ("sucesso".equals(c.getMsg())) {
                String sql = "INSERT INTO pessoa (nome, dataNascimento, cpf,foto) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
                PreparedStatement pstm;

                pstm = c.getConexao().prepareStatement(sql);

                pstm.setString(1, pessoa.getNome());                
                pstm.setDate(2, pessoa.getDataNascimento());
                pstm.setString(3, pessoa.getCpf());                
                pstm.setBytes(4, pessoa.getFoto());
                pstm.execute();

            }


        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(UsuarioDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    }
```

E essa é minha Servlet de inclusão, onde esta apresentando erro quando dou um getParameter na foto, onde ele diz que devo mudar pra String, alguém sabe como ajustar na servlet?

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
           PessoaDAO pessoadao = new PessoaDAO();

        String nome = request.getParameter("nome");              


            String dataNasc = request.getParameter("dataNascimento");

            SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            java.util.Date dataUtil = formato.parse(dataNasc);

            java.sql.Date dataSql = new java.sql.Date(dataUtil.getTime());

        String cpf = request.getParameter("cpf");   
        // Diz que devo mudar de byte para String 
        byte[] foto = request.getParameter("foto");

        int idUsuario =     Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("idUsuario"));
        Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(nome,dataSql,cpf,foto);

        pessoadao.addPessoa(pessoa);
           Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        RequestDispatcher rd; 
            UsuarioDAO udao=new UsuarioDAO();
            for(Usuario u : udao.getLista()){
                if(u.getIdUsuario()==idUsuario){
                    usuario=u;
                    break;
                }

            }

                request.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);

                    rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/cadpessoa.jsp");
                    rd.forward(request, response);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ServletIncluiPessoa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Tente:

```
String fotoString = request.getParameter("foto");
byte[] foto = fotoString.getBytes();
```

Answer (score 0):

Não sei muito bem qual a necessidade da sua aplicação.

Mas se possivel, o ideal seria você guardar suas imagens em alguma diretório ou servidor FTP, e salvar apenas o caminho no banco de dados, para que a a aplicação consiga recuperar a imagem.

Guardar imagens no banco de dados trás uma serie de problemas, entre ele o aumento da base de dados, dificultando assim a manutenção do mesmo.

Answer (score -4):

A pratica mais usada é como Alysson disse brilhantemente, é fazer o upload da imagem pro server, recuperar a string do caminho e salvar essa string em obviamente, campo string no banco de dados... assim você consegue exibir essa imagem pelo caminho dela no ftp por exemplo